# Angularjs drop-down is not showing untill field is changed and loading indicator not work proparely

Tags: angularjs

In my Angularjs app I'm trying to make a drop-down multi select that loads data from JSON at first and when I click on "load more" get more data from JSON and while loading show loading indicator.
But It's not show anything until I change the field and the loading not working proparly.
appreciate any help.
my data is this:

```
[
{
    "item": "South Korea",
    "category": "Asia",
    "flag": false
}, {
    "item": "England",
    "category": "Europe",
    "flag": false
}, {
    "item": "Japan",
    "category": "Asia",
    "flag": false
}, {
    "item": "Denmark",
    "category": "Europe",
    "flag": false
}, {
    "item": "North Korea",
    "category": "Asia",
    "flag": false
}, {
    "item": "Geramany",
    "category": "Europe",
    "flag": false
}, {
    "item": "China",
    "category": "Asia",
    "flag": false
}, {
    "item": "Spain",
    "category": "Europe",
    "flag": false
}, {
    "item": "India",
    "category": "Asia",
    "flag": false
}, {
    "item": "Italy",
    "category": "Europe",
    "flag": false
}, {
    "item": "Tailand",
    "category": "Asia",
    "flag": false
}, {
    "item": "Portugal",
    "category": "Europe",
    "flag": false
}
]
```

```js
"use strict";

var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {

 /*  ===== VARIABLES =====   */

 /* loading indicator */
 $scope.dataLoading = true;

 // data variables
 $scope.data2Show = [];
 $scope.data = [];

 // variables for get requests
 var counter = 0;
 var chunks = 5;

 // variables for checkbox
 $scope.selectedItems = [];

 //variables for opening dropdown
 $scope.selectEnable = false;

 // method for opening dropdown
 $scope.openSelect = function () {
  $scope.selectEnable = !$scope.selectEnable;
 };

 /*  ===== Functions =====   */

 // initial success method
 function onSuccess(response) {
  for (let i = 0; i < chunks; i++) {
   $scope.data.push(response.data[i]);
  }
  counter += chunks;
 }

 // Error method 
 function onError(response) {
  console.log("error");
 }

 // load more success method
 function loadMoreSuccess(response) {
  for (let i = counter; i < (counter + chunks); i++) {
   $scope.data.push(response.data[i]);
  }
  counter += chunks;
 }

 /* get methods */
 // initial get method
 $http({
   method: "GET",
   url: "data.json"
  })
  .then(onSuccess)
  .catch(onError)
  .finally(function () {
   $scope.dataLoading = false;
  });

 // load more method
 $scope.loadMore = function () {
  $http({
    method: "GET",
    url: "data.json"
   })
   .then(loadMoreSuccess)
   .catch(onError)
   .finally(function () {
    $scope.dataLoading = false;
   });
 };

 /* when checkbox changes if the item is checked 
 is alteady in the selected
 items it will remove it because it means that 
 the checkbox is unchecked and if the item
 is not in selected items it will add that */
 $scope.itemChecked = function (data) {
  var selected = $scope.selectedItems.indexOf(data.item);
  if (selected == -1) {
   $scope.selectedItems.push(data.item);
  } else {
   $scope.selectedItems.splice(selected, 1);
  }
 };

 // when the searchField content changes this function executes
 $scope.filter = function () {
  if (!$scope.searchField) {
   $scope.data2Show = angular.copy($scope.data);
   /* if searchField is empty make a copy of our data */
  } else {
   /* if searchField is not empty data2show will be empty and iterate the data array and for each element if the searched sentence is in the data array that data will be pushed into the data2show array */
   $scope.data2Show = [];
   $scope.data.map(function (itm) {
    if (itm.item.indexOf($scope.searchField) != -1) {
     $scope.data2Show.push(itm);
    }
   });
  }
 };

});
```

```css
ul li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#loadMore {
  text-align: center;
  color: #aaa;
  background: #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#category {
  text-align: center;
  background: #ddd;
}

#listContainer {
  width: 20%;
}

span {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js
"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/style.css">
</head>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <input type="text" ng-click="openSelect()">
  <div id="selectContainer" ng-show="selectEnable">
    <div>{{selectedItems.toString()}}</div>
    <input type="text" id="searchField" ng-model="searchField" ng-change="filter()">
    <div id="listContainer">
      <ul id="innerContainer">
        <li ng-repeat="data in data2Show" ng-model="data2show">
          <input type="checkbox" ng-change="itemChecked(data)" name="select" ng-model="data.flag" ng-checked="isChecked(data)"> {{data.item}}
        </li>
        <div ng-show="dataLoading" ng-model="dataLoading">loading...</div>
        <li id="loadMore" ng-click="loadMore()">
          load more
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="script/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **Loading indicator**: For the loading indicator to show `$scope.dataLoading` has to be set to `true`. This is only done once initially. It should also be done in the `$scope.loadMore` method before the call to `HttpService.get`
- **New Elements not shown**: You store the elements that you load in the `$scope.loadMore` only in `$state.data`. To be displayed they must also be stored in `$scope.data2show`. So just invoke `$scope.filter` after the new elements have been loaded from the server.